# Failed to launch hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

[here is partial error about launching hbase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Omi.png)
I don't know whether the zookeeper or jdk is wrong.

PS:

1. my java version is the same as my javac version;
2. my zookeeper has launched successfully.

Does anyone have the same error as me? I'll appreciate to you if you can help me launch it.

Comment: [root@master hbase]# cat logs/hbase-root-master-master.masterdomain.out
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hbase/thirdparty/com/google/protobuf/ServiceException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

Comment: when I run "hbase shell', just got the error "Error: Could not find or load main class org.jruby.Main".  Help!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you just post the error stacktrace on the question? Ans what is the protobuf version installed on your machine? It looks like you dont have it installed.

Comment: hbase-2.2.6-bin.tar.gz   &    hadoop-3.1.4.tar.gz

Comment: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hbase/thirdparty/com/google/protobuf/ServiceException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)

Comment: at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.com.google.protobuf.ServiceException